# What is the command to connect to a database(MS Access) saved anywhere on the PC without specifying the full path name

Tags: c#

```
public void DatabaseConnection()
{
    connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source =..\\..\\TaxApp.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
    connection.Open();

}
```

Comment: There is no way to avoid this. You need to specify the path. (Full or partial from a reference point but still...) Perhaps you mean to store the path in the config file where you can easily change it to adapt to your customers environment

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a language that allows you to construct the path, such as C#:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

will, by default, give you the path to `c:\ProgramData` folder, which is shared among all users.

So:

```
string AccessDbPath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), 
    "YourAppFolder\\TaxApp.accdb");
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't store fixed paths in your code. This will make your application very difficult to install on your customers PCs.
Knowing this, the NET framework provides an infrastructure to store this kind of informations in external XML based file (named `yourexename.exe.config` when you release the application and simply `app.config` inside your project).
You can store there this kind of information that need to be changed on a customer by customer base.

So you app.config could have a section made in this way

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="DatabasePath" value="C:\programdata\MyApp\Database.accdb" />
</appSettings>
```

Inside your program you could read and use this value using this code

```
string dbFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabasePath"].ToString();
connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                                  Data source =" + dbFile + 
                                 ";Persist Security Info=False");
```

You could even store the whole connection string using the project properties menu and adding a new entry of type ConnectionString in the Settings page.

Again, what you type there will be stored in the app.config file in a specific section

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDb" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
             Data source=C:\programdata\MyApp\Database.accdb;
            Persist Security Info=False";/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and you can read it with

```
string myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb"].ConnectionString;
```

See [ConfigurationManager class on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)